# Insert data into a table from a stored procedure returning two sets of data

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server which is returning two sets of data from two select statements. I'm trying to insert the second select into a table.

But I'm trying to do this with a

```
INSERT INTO TABLE 
   EXEC SP
```

statement.

Is there anyway to do that!?

Comment: As far as I know, T-SQL itself isn't able to handle this situation - you cannot access / fetch the second dataset being returned. The only working solution I know of is using C#/VB.NET and the ADO.NET library, which allows you to execute some SQL (query or stored procedure) and then get the first, second, third, fourth etc. returned data set and handle it

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server can't handle multiple result sets in this scenario.

without seeing your procedure I can't be certain but one possible workaround and something I have used before would be to modify the procedure with an optional flag parameter to prevent it from returning the first recordset, then pass 1 for the optional parameter to skip the first query.

For example

```
create or alter procedure MyProc
<any existing parameters>,
@flag bit=0
as

if @flag=0
begin

/* Code for first result set */

end

/* Code for second result set */

go
```